# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The MySQL query got following error.

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'scope.full_name' in 'where clause'

Here are two tables as below.

1.scope:

```
 +-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+------+----------+--------------+
    | handle_id | model_id | define_name | full_name    | name | file     | parent_scope |
    +-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+------+----------+--------------+
    |  15859248 |        0 | tb          | tb           | tb   | 12755864 |            0 |
    |  15859360 |        0 | RCA         | tb.RCA       | RCA  | 12755864 |     15859248 |
    |  15859472 |        0 | FA          | tb.RCA.x1    | x1   | 12755864 |     15859360 |
    |  15859584 |        0 | HA          | tb.RCA.x1.x1 | x1   | 12755864 |     15859472 |
    |  15859696 |        0 | HA          | tb.RCA.x1.x2 | x2   | 12755864 |     15859472 |
    |  15859808 |        0 | FA          | tb.RCA.x2    | x2   | 12755864 |     15859360 |
    |  15859920 |        0 | HA          | tb.RCA.x2.x1 | x1   | 12755864 |     15859808 |
    |  15860032 |        0 | HA          | tb.RCA.x2.x2 | x2   | 12755864 |     15859808 |
    |  15860144 |        0 | FA          | tb.RCA.x3    | x3   | 12755864 |     15859360 |
    |  15860256 |        0 | HA          | tb.RCA.x3.x1 | x1   | 12755864 |     15860144 |
    |  15860368 |        0 | HA          | tb.RCA.x3.x2 | x2   | 12755864 |     15860144 |
    |  15860480 |        0 | FA          | tb.RCA.x4    | x4   | 12755864 |     15859360 |
    |  15860592 |        0 | HA          | tb.RCA.x4.x1 | x1   | 12755864 |     15860480 |
    |  15860704 |        0 | HA          | tb.RCA.x4.x2 | x2   | 12755864 |     15860480 |
    +-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+------+----------+--------------+
```

2.file:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| handle_id | model_id | max_time | min_time | name                                                              | scale_unit |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|  12755864 |        0 |    10000 |        0 | /directory/ART.txt                                               | 1ns        |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Query command is:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `file` WHERE `scope`.`full_name`='tb.RCA';
```

I understand backticks in MySQL means " allow spaces and other special characters (except for backticks, obviously) in table/column names", but even the following command causes same error.

```
 SELECT name FROM file WHERE scope.full_name='tb.RCA';
```

For more information, MySQL server version is **5.7.20** on Linux system.

Comment: But you have no table `scope` there...

Comment: The first table "1.scope" is table scope .

Comment: You only select from `file`, not from `scope`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the tables like this:

```
SELECT f.name
FROM file f 
JOIN scope s on s.file = f.handle_id
WHERE s.full_name = 'tb.RCA'
```

The line `JOIN scope s on s.file = f.id` joins the table data using the column `file` from the `scope` table and the `handle_id` column from the `file` table.

I have linked [this website](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins) many times for questions like this - it's a great visual explanation of joins.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reference a table, the table needs to be included in the `FROM` clause somewhere.  Hence, `scope` is not understood.  One way to fix the problem uses a `JOIN`.  However that runs the risk of duplicates in the `scope` table affecting the results.

I think your actual intention is captured by `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT f.name
FROM file f
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM scope s WHERE s.handle_id = f.file AND s.full_name = 'tb.RCA');
```

Note that backticks are not needed if you name your columns and tables easily.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use both the table

Try with this

```
SELECT file.name FROM file,scope WHERE scope.full_name='tb.RCA';
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.